# ASP.NET MVC 6 Beta8 Project Upgraded from Beta5 crashes IIS Express - The main function returned unexpectedly with status code 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, beta

I have a very simple mvc project that was beta5 and upgraded to beta8. During that upgrade, I changed the reference for IIS from Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS to Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IISPlatformHandler as well as changing the reference for kestrel (which isn't important, because the kestrel server works fine). Whenever I try to run the project with IIS Express, it immediately crashes and return the error

> "The main function returned unexpectedly with status code 0."

When the page is reloaded, the error changes to

> "The main function returned unexpectedly with status code  -2147023829."

I can't find any documentation on these status codes and there seems to be only three issues related to it. They're all marked as issues on the Asp.Net github page, and two of them don't relate to this issue. The other one says that this problem can be called by versioning issues in the publish profiles, so I checked them and they're all updated.

That one is located here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/735

And the other two can be found here:

- https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/1564
- https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/1319

Here's my project.json:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-beta8",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "System.Net.Sockets": "4.0.10-beta-23409"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5001"
  },


  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": {}
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

The of the project can be found at https://github.com/ThePlatinumTaco/TSA_2016/tree/master/src/TSA%202016 but if there are any resources there that are helpful, say so in the comments so they can be added here to help anybody else with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a web.config in your wwwroot folder. They added it from beta-8 I just upgraded my vNext project to the RC1.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgolois/DivineChMS/master/src/DivineChMS.Web/wwwroot/web.config

Read this as well: http://damienbod.com/2015/10/16/asp-net-5-updating-to-beta8-from-older-beta-versions/